# Call js function defined in a babel script from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs

I am including my js file into my main html file like so

`<script type="text/babel" src="js/scripts.js"></script>`

Then I call one of my functions like so

`<div class="allButton" id="completeAll" onclick="showAll('completeColumn');">Show All (...)</div>`

the function looks like this

```
function showAll(column) {
  $('div[id^='+column+']').removeClass('hide');
};
```

When I click the button(div) I get this error
`Uncaught ReferenceError: showAll is not defined`

I am using the `text/babel` as my script type because the file contains React JS stuff.
I have no idea why I simply cannot call my function. I am extremely new to ReactJS and Babel. (note: I am not using npm/gulp due to limitations)

Any help and/or advice would be appreciated

Comment: The browser doesn't recognize `type="text/babel"`, so the script is not being evaluated and the `showAll` function doesn't exist.

Comment: If you're using Babel, you should really compile the code *before* it hits the browser then just include the compiled code with a standard `<script>`.

Comment: I think it used to be possible to use babel transpilation on the client side, but seems to be discontinued / discouraged: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/

Answer (score 3):

If you just define your function as follows you will be able to call it within the HTML.

```
window.showAll = function showAll(column) {
    // your code here...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not exported your `showAll` function. When you transpile a JS/JSX file with Babel and bundle it to a `scripts.js` file (using Browserify or similar utilities), you must make sure to export your module (which tells your bundler to package it into your bundled file).

Your code should look like this:

```
var showAll = function(column) {
  $('div[id^='+column+']').removeClass('hide');
};

module.exports = showAll;
```

This tells your bundler that your `showAll` method needs to be exported and available to other referenced namespaces.

Comment: The thing is OP doesn't transpile the code and expects it to automagically work ;)

Comment: Transpiling would matter anyway. Its valid ES5. What I'm worried about, is that OP in not bundling his code properly to expose it to the browser.